# Rendering content of a 2d array in JSX

Tags: arrays, reactjs, async-await

I have some React problems that I don't seem to understand. What I want to do is to simply render the content of a 2d array. My code looks like this:

```
class CrosswordPage extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            crossword: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //Calling a function which populates a 2d array with letters. For example:
        //[["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]
        const crossword = parseCrossword();
        this.setState({ crossword: crossword });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className='crossword-container'>
                <img src='/crossword.png' alt='' />
                <div className='grid-container'>
                    {Object.keys(this.state.crossword).map(keyOuter => {
                        return Object.keys(this.state.crossword[keyOuter]).map(keyInner => {
                            return (
                                <li>{this.state.crossword[keyOuter][keyInner]}</li>
                            );
                        });
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CrosswordPage;
```

```
export const parseCrossword = () => {
    var editableCellsMatrix = Array(24).fill().map(() => Array(20).fill(""));
    
    //This section fills the array with letters. Don't think the logic is relevant for this question!

    return editableCellsMatrix;
}
```

If I console.log my 2d array, it looks alright but for some reason only empty strings are listed on the page. If I instead fill the array with "A"s before populating it with the correct letters, console log will show the correct array while the page will show a list of "A"s.

I believe I'm missing something regarding synchronous/asyncronous. I've heard that console.log is synchronous which could explain why it logs the fully populated array.

How can I make sure that when I render the list elements, the array is fully populated with letters?

Comment: Hmm, why are you using `Object.keys` on arrays? That gets the keys from objects.

Comment: I found that in an answer somewhere. I've also used:
{
  this.state.crossword.map(item => {
    return item.map(cell => {
      return <div>{cell}</div>
    })
  })
}